# Convert regex to Oracle database regex

Tags: java, sql, regex, oracle

I'm trying to convert this regex:

```
^.*[^a-z1-9\-].*$
```

to a regex to be used in an oracle database query. What I want to do is to find all rows that contains at least one character in the column `name` different of `a-z`, `0-9` and `-`.

The query

```
select * from device where regexp_like(ctnmname, '^.*[^a-z1-9\\-].*$')
```

returns all rows in the table.

**EDIT**

The problem was the regex with the `0` and a escaped `-`. It works with the regex `^.*[^a-z0-9-].*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex itself looks OK. You might want to make it case-sensitive and include the `0`:

```
SELECT * FROM device WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(mycolumn, '^.*[^a-z0-9-].*$', 'c');
```

Answer (score 1):

As the dash is the last in the character class, you won't need to escape it:

```
where regexp_like(ctnmname, '^.*[^a-z1-9-].*$')
```

However

```
where regexp_instr(ctnmname, '[^a-z1-9-]') > 0
```

might be easier to read...

See also [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c33a/2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer beny23, but still not working. Gives the same result.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some of the values present in your `ctnmname` column?

Answer (score 0):

```
where not regexp_like(ctnmname, '^(\w|-)*$')
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c522e/7)